# Always pending at kubernetes service external ip

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy a demo Wordpress app on Kubernetes with Helm.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/wordpress/README.md

I was following this page and tried first command. Everything looks clear. Pods are running. PVs are bound. But when I look at service with `kubectl get svc`, the external ip is always says pending. What can I do?

When i try `minikube service my-release-wordpress`  it gives me local ip address. But I want it deploy externally.

Comment: default service.type = LoadBalancer provisions a loadbalancer on the cloud infrastructure your cluster is running. this won't work on minikube.

Comment: how can i solve this problem then?

Comment: @ufukbasural If you are just doing this for testing purpose, you can use service equals NodePort. Then, you can use your app using NodeIP:NodePort.
NodePort can be checked using ```kubectl get svc -n <namespace>```